# Just, a noun. (?)

Tags: word-usage, etymology, nouns, adjectives, connotation

I can't seem to find an answer to whether the adjective "just" has ever been used as a noun in the history of the English language.

Comment: No. The noun is *justice*, and adjectives fit fine into those sentences — consider *what he did was stupid* and *it would be stupid to claim ...* (Or *difficult, foolish, presumptuous*, ...)

Comment: Sure, that would be the grammatical explanation, but I just wondered - ever as a noun.

Comment: Most adjectives can be used as nouns if you put a *the* in front of them, and *just* is no exception. For example, from the Bible *For He maketh His sun to rise on the evil and on the good, and sendeth rain on the just and on the unjust.* Here, *the just* means *the just people*.

Comment: That is exactly right! So the answer is a kind of yes then :)

Comment: ... And the meek shall inherit the Earth. I'd have problems with _the utter_.

Comment: It is worth noting that "just" (n.) is unusual in that, usually, nominalised adjectives are (i) in the singular, (ii) they are uncountable and (iii) take a plural verb: "The poor/rich/ **are** revolting." Whereas "the just"  ( a just person) can be singular with a singular concord: 1871   B. Jowett " Awakening of Western Legal Thought" (1942) i. 44   The just is always a loser in comparison with the unjust.

Comment: Why is this considered off-topic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just* can be a noun, and has been used that way since Middle English:

> The prophetis..that bifore teelden of the comynge of the iust.
>   [Wycliffe Bible](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/AFZ9170.0001.001/1:71.8?rgn=div2;view=fulltext), c1384

(See more [modern translations of this passage](https://biblehub.com/acts/7-52.htm).)

This is similar to how we often talk about **the rich** and **the poor**.

However, in your sentences it is just an adjective.